# Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger Extension for Visual Studio Code not working

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins

I am starting to learn writing Office Addins with Javascript. I have spent alot time on MS website going through tutorials and documentation. I figure I would try my hand on a few of the Addin walk throughs.

I am using VS Code with Node.js. After having successfully creating a few examples and worked through the creation process.

I figure I would step up the debug environment so I could really get into the learning/development phase. I followed the instructions on the following MS webpage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-with-vs-extension using my functioning addin example.

When I start the debugger inside VS Code, I get the following error:

```
Discovering targets via http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/list HTTP GET failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222
```

I am assuming I have a configuration problem somewhere, I have search for these errors but haven't found anyone out there that has experienced this problem.

Any suggests would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got a few comments on my demo video where I show how to do this with the exact same error.

You can find the video instruction and the comments on the fail here:
[How to: Debug OfficeJs Add-ins using Office Debug Extension in Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVFUUC18d6s)

So I went back and tested it again to in fact run into the same issue:
[Live Stream researching this exact issue](https://youtu.be/voN_PVnFeBQ)

The way I was able to solve it was by changing back my Default Browser (Chrome) to Edge 'Legacy' (NOT the Chromium version using a different WebView). Running the process again got it to work. After that I was able to change back Chrome as default browser and it was still working.

It is (as you can see in the research video) important to see that your TaskManager shows the WWAHost entry in the details. If that is not there you are most likely running the incorrect WebView.

WebView2, the version used by Edge Chromium, is (not yet) supported but will be here soon.

Comment: Maarten thank you so much for your video. I have followed your steps, but I am still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maarten Thanks so much again for the time that you took to solve this problem, but it is still not working. When I switch the webview and default browser I get the same result, no connection error. I first use the this command:  npx office-addin-dev-settings webview .\manifest.xml edge , the result is "The web view type is set to Microsoft Edge (Chromium)." I then use:  npx office-addin-dev-settings webview .\manifest.xml edge-legacy, the result is "The web view type is set to legacy Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML)." either way I get the error plus i do see for both webviews "WWAHost" in taskmanager

Comment: I have tried starting from scratch, new project switching default browser still no good. It like the commands are not switching browsers. Any suggestions.

Comment: See my comment on your question at my YouTube channel here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voN_PVnFeBQ&lc=UgxHvmPx3eoVXMIjxDJ4AaABAg.9KxNfJkXm1H9L505H5sSDb I did some additional research on this in my latest live coding session based on your comment on YT. The debugging system changed a bit (again) so I probably need to record a new start to end demo but if you have 2 hours you can watch the recording from last thursday ;-)